# I am getting img tag from json in vuejs but the page is not running either

Tags: vue.js

I keep the img tag and the p tag in vuejs and json. then when I use the json object on a page the p tags work but the img tag does not. conclusion:[image]

When I click on this page, I want to send the object to the other page with a query and generate html code on the other page.

html:

```html
<div class="faq-item-btn">
            <div  @click="send($t('faqs.faq2.title'),$t('faqs.faq2.content'))">
              <img slot="icon" src="@/assets/img/ico_next.png">
            </div>
          </div>
```

js:

```js
send(title, content) {
      this.$router.push({
        path: "/faqitem",
        query: {
          title: title,
          content: content,
        },
      })
    }
```

While p tags and title tags are working in the text that comes with the content I receive on this page, the img tag unfortunately does not work.
html:

```html
<div class="content">
        <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
        <div v-html="content"> </div>
</div>
```

js:

```js
methods: {
    sendContent(){
      this.title = this.$route.query.title;
      this.content = this.$route.query.content;
    }

  },
  created(){
    this.sendContent();
  },
```

Comment: It's really scary to send html data in queries.

Comment: how should i post from one page to another page

Comment: You can save it in store and access to it from another page.

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand fully but what is `v-html` used for here? Also, what doesn't work with the image. Please check your browser's devtools to see what is broken.